# Is there any way to improve the gross CC/cycle gained from exploited systems?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Right now, Arissa Lavigny Duval isn't doing so hot. We may have overextended a little bit, discovering that CC overheads don't increase on a linear scale. My theory is, that the best way to contribute to the power, would be to increase the gross CC gain from exploited systems. Is there any way to increase the profit margins of systems we already exploit, and already have no upkeep cost for?

Comment: It seems turning systems to your favorable government type is helpful, but this may only be for fortification purposes (for example: ALD favors Patronage governments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. CC/cycle is based on the population of all exploited systems. Since there is no way to increase population of a system, and one cannot create more systems, there is no way to increase this number. The only thing that can be done with these sort of deficit-causing systems is to shed them through turmoil by not fortifying them.